# Google+ button for sharing an article (just like TweetMeme) available?

Tags: social-network

I need a button to share the current node to Google+?
Is there a module to implement it?

I already have a standalone one (TweetMeme for twitter and another one for facebook )

Comment: You can easily implement the +1 button using Google's code in your template: http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/ You don't need a module to do this unless you are looking for more complex functionality.

Comment: I thought It was required to grab the url, but I see it's dynamic with JS

Comment: Yes, it'll just pick up on your URL. We use it this way on a number of sites successfully. You might want to investigate setting a canonical URL that would benefit this and SEO generally.

Comment: what is TweetMeme

Answer (score 2):

For modules that implement the Google+

1. [Google Plus One](http://drupal.org/project/google_plusone)
2. [Social media](http://drupal.org/project/socialmedia)
3. [Easy Social](http://drupal.org/project/easy_social)